# SSIS Converting a char to a boolean/bit

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package to load data; as you may recall there are flags that are in data files as Y/N char(1) when I am trying to load them as bit flags into SQL Server.  I am specifying the columns in the data file as `String [DT_STR]` and I have a data conversion task to convert them to booleans based on the following expression (I received the same conversion error just specifying them as DT_BOOL to begin with, despite SSIS asking me to say what values it should consider as boolean):

```
[ColumnName] == "Y" ? (DT_BOOL)1 : (DT_BOOL)0
```

Running the package gives an error and tells me `Invalid character value for cast specification` and `The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data` on the actual import to SQL Server (via an OLE DB Destination).

What am I missing here to get it to properly convert?

Comment: I've been looking at doing something *incredibly* similar to this, but I can't find anywhere in the Data Conversion transformation where to do it.  Where is it that you're defining this?

Comment: I believe I found it - it's actually the Derived Column transformation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using a derived column and, instead of replacing the char columns, creating new columns set to type of `DT_BOOL` like so:

```
[Recycled] == "Y" ? True : False
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, you cannot replace any column in SSIS with a column of a different type, you always have to add new columns.

Comment: Although in the conversion task you can make another column with the same name, but in my experience, not all components later in the pipeline will display the fully qualified name as component.column, so it's annoying and dangerous.

Comment: Right - I found that out the hard way ;-)

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
(DT_BOOL)([ColumnName] == "Y" ? 1 : 0)
```

This also has the advantage of automatically setting the data type of the derived column correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with

(DT_BOOL)([ColumnName] == "Y" ? 1 : 0)

and I could only get it to work by taking OUT the "(DT_BOOL)" portion out of the expression and putting the job of converting it to a boolean onto the "Data Type" part by selecting "Boolean [DT_BOOL].  No problems after that.