# SSIS: Handling 1/0 Fields in Data Flow Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am building a Data Flow Task in an SSIS package that pulls data in from an OLE DB Source (MS Access table), converts data types through a Data Conversion Transformation, then routes that data to an OLE DB Destination (SQL Server table).

I have a number of BIT columns for flag variables in the destination table and am having trouble with truncation when converting these 1/0 columns to (DT_BYTES,1). Converting from DT_WSTR and DT_I4 to (DT_BYTES,1) results in the same truncation, and I have verified that it is happening at that step through the Data Viewer.

It appears that I need to create a derived column similar to what is described in the answers to the question linked below, but instead of converting to DT_BOOL, I need to convert to (DT_BYTES,1), as casting from DT_BOOL to DT_BYTES is apparently illegal?

[SSIS Converting a char to a boolean/bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554092/ssis-converting-a-char-to-a-boolean-bit)

I have made several attempts at creating a derived column with variations of the logic below, but haven’t had any luck.  I am guessing that I need to use Hex literals in the “1 : 0” portion of the expression, but I haven’t been able to find valid syntax for that:

```
(DT_BYTES,1)([Variable_Name] == (DT_I4)1 ? 1 : 0)
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly?  I can’t be the first person to need to insert BIT data into a SQL Server table, and the process above just seems unnecessarily complex to me.

Comment: Have you tried (DT_BOOL)([Your-Column-Name] == "1" ? 1 : 0)`, for the string columns (and the same without double quotes for the integer conversions)?

Comment: The expression you provided works great, but the issue is I can't then get the DT_BOOL value to convert to DT_BYTES when trying to get the records into the OLE DB Destination. I get the error "The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types DT_BOOL and "DT_BYTES". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'd misunderstood. I don't have SSIS in front of me right now but I can help tomorrow. Can you post the MSAccess and SQL Server data types.

Comment: Why use `DT_BYTES` for boolean data? http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-and-ssis-data-types/

Comment: Sorry, really stupid mistake here, thanks for your time.  Your prompt for me to take a closer look at the SQL Server data types caused me to see that the table columns were actually set to type Binary(1) instead of Bit, which is why they were showing up as (DT_BYTES,1) instead of DT_BOOL in the OLE DB Destination in SSIS.  Re-creating the table and giving the columns the appropriate data type, I was able to just convert these fields to DT_BOOL in the Data Conversion Transformation and the data is flowing through fine now.